# How to filter Microsoft Service using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, service

How to filter the services that belong to Microsoft [including applications such as Office, IIS, AD, EXCH and so on] using PowerShell [v1.0 preferably].

In the "`msconfig.msc -> Services Tab`" there is a check box that reads "Hide all Microsoft Services", I'm looking for the same functionality of filtering the services that belong to MS.

Is this a possibility? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a way to start:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Property * | Select DisplayName,PathName | %{ Try { if([System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("$($_.PathName.ToString().Split("-")[0].Split("/")[0])").LegalCopyright -like "*Microsoft*") {"$($_.DisplayName) is a Microsoft Service"}} catch {}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction Savindra, we've taken this and looking to add functionality such as Services belonging to a particular Application like IIS, EXCH and so on.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further help on refining the same. This was the quickest way that came to my mind that time. We can make this even better if required. But the best way to find the details of the same (according to me) is through file copyright information.

Answer (score 2):

I used the code above to make this.  I was interested in all the non-MS services and a more versatile output format.

```
$services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Property Name,DisplayName,PathName | Select 
Name, DisplayName,PathName
$serviceList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($service in $services) {
  Try {
    $path = $service.Pathname.tostring().replace('"','')
    $cri = ([System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path)).legalcopyright
    if ($cri -notlike "*Microsoft*") {
      $serviceList += $service
    }
  } catch {}
}
$serviceList
```