# Filter microsoft service from `wmic service get` command

Tags: wmic

I'm using wmic to enumerate installed services:

```
wmic service get
```

Is it possible to hide microsoft service from it?

The query returns the following fields, none of them seems to be helpful:

```
AcceptPause AcceptStop Caption CheckPoint CreationClassName Description DesktopInteract DisplayName ErrorControl ExitCode InstallDate Name PathName ProcessId ServiceSpecificExitCode ServiceType Started StartMode StartName State Status SystemCreationClassName SystemName TagId WaitHint
```

Comment: What's your aim and what did you expect to get as info to be helpful for you ?

Comment: @Hackoo I'd like to display non-windows services, e.g vmware services

Comment: Can you tell me if this command is useful or not for you ? `Wmic service where (state="running") get caption, name, startmode, state`

Comment: @Hackoo state=running returns all services

Comment: Try this command `sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "vmware"`

Comment: OR you can filter with PowerShell Command `Get-WmiObject win32_service | where { $_.Caption -notmatch "Windows" -and $_.PathName -notmatch "Windows" -and $_.PathName -notmatch "policyhost.exe" -and $_.Name -ne "LSM" }`

Comment: Please check my last update answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command can did the trick :

```
WMIC service where "Not PathName like '%Micro%' AND Not PathName like '%Windows%'" get Name,DisplayName,PathName,State,Status
```

And you can do it with Powershell script too :

Refer to this answer here [How to filter Microsoft Service using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064102/how-to-filter-microsoft-service-using-powershell?answertab=active#tab-top).

You can filter the ***Non-Microsoft services*** with powershell script :

```
$services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Property Name,DisplayName,PathName | Select Name, DisplayName,PathName
$serviceList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($service in $services) {
  Try {
    $path = $service.Pathname.tostring().replace('"','')
    $cri = ([System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($path)).legalcopyright
    if ($cri -notlike "*Microsoft*") {
      $serviceList += $service
    }
  } catch {}
}
$serviceList
```

***Edit : on 02/11/2019 Vbscript Version***

Here is another version using vbscript in order to export the output results with Excel.

Just copy and paste this code below as ***Non-Microsoft-Services.vbs*** and execute it by double click.

```vbs
Option Explicit
' Non-Microsoft-Services.vbs
Dim objExcel,strComputer,objWMIService
Dim State,colServices,x,objService,objWorksheet,objWorkbook
' Create a new and blank spreadsheet:
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Add
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Name = "Services Non-Microsoft"
objWorksheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 3

' Format the cell A1 and add the text: Service Name
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Service Name"
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = TRUE
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
' Format the cell A2 and add the text: Display Name
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Display Name"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = TRUE
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 2
'*************************************************
' Format the cell A3 and add the text: State
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value = "State"
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Font.Bold = TRUE
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 2
'*************************************************
' Format the cell A4 and add the text: Executable Path
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Executable Path"
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Font.Bold = TRUE
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Font.ColorIndex = 2
'*************************************************
' Format the cell A5 and add the text: Description
objExcel.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Description"
objExcel.Cells(1, 5).Font.Bold = TRUE
objExcel.Cells(1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
objExcel.Cells(1, 5).Font.ColorIndex = 2
' Find the Non-Microsoft Windows services on this computer
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Service where Not PathName like '%Micro%' AND Not PathName like '%Windows%'")
' Write each service to Excel, starting in A2
x = 1
For Each objService in colServices
    x = x + 1
    objExcel.Cells(x, 1) = objService.Name
    objExcel.Cells(x, 2) = objService.DisplayName
    objExcel.Cells(x, 3) = objService.State
    objExcel.Cells(x, 4) = objService.PathName
    objExcel.Cells(x, 5) = objService.Description
    State = objService.Started
    If State Then 
        Cellule x,3,"Running"
        objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        objExcel.Cells(x, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        objExcel.Cells(x, 4).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        objExcel.Cells(x, 5).Font.ColorIndex = 10
    ELSE
        Cellule X,3,"Stopped"
        objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        objExcel.Cells(x, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        objExcel.Cells(x, 4).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        objExcel.Cells(x, 5).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    end if
Next

objExcel.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Dim FSO : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Network : Set Network = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim Computer : Computer = Network.ComputerName
Dim xlVer,objXL
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
' Check Excel Version (12.0 = 2007)
xlVer = Split(objXL.Version,".")(0) 
If xlVer >= "12" Then
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\Non-Microsoft-Services_" & Computer & ".xlsx"
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
' 56 = Excel 97-2003
' Voir la page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx
Else
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\Non-Microsoft-Services_" & Computer & ".xls",56
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Cellule(X,NC,chaine)
    objExcel.Cells(X,NC).Value = Chaine
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
'Function to determine the current directory
Function GetPath()
    Dim path
    path = WScript.ScriptFullName
    GetPath = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\"))
End Function
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a screenshot what i got as result with this vbscript :

[image]

Comment: I get your idea. I will filter ms services by service executable path